# iOS apple-app-site-association - does it need to be off the root of my server?

Tags: ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, capacitor, apple-app-site-associate

I am trying to configure deep linking for my Capacitor App and am following the instructions here:  https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/deep-links. Apple mentions that

> "The file needs to be accessible via HTTPS—without any redirects—at
> https:///apple-app-site-association or
> https:///.well-known/apple-app-site-association. Next, you
> need to handle universal links in your app"

And

> "Upload the apple-app-site-association file to your HTTPS web server. You can place the file at the root of your server or in the .well-known subdirectory."

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

---

My questions is: does the .well-known directory absolutely need to be off the root of my server?

We use Google Cloud and Kubernetes and the website I need to link with does not live at `domain.com`, it lives at `domain.com/myapp`. I need to be able to serve the apple-site-association file at domain.com/myapp/.well-known/apple-app-site-association.

However, when I serve the association file at:

```
domain.com/myapp/.well-known/apple-app-site-association
```

I get:

```
"Error cannot fetch app site association" from https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool"
```

I've tested deep linking with my app on a device (just to see if the validator was wrong) but am always routed to our website and not our application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `.well-known` must be off the root.  It can't be under `/myapp` and you can't use a redirect.

You can specify a path in the site association file, so the universal links you use can contain the `/myApp` path.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that the `.well-known` directory cannot be modified (for other reasons). I put the `apple-app-site-association` directly in the root of my site and it works fine.